# Can't generate signed APK in AndroidStudio, 'java.io.IOException'

Tags: android, gradle, build, apk

I have a problem with generating signed APK in Android Studio.

> **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.**
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Ahmed\StudioProjects\android1\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-25.2.0.aar\8a6c38a056e2992b7f752213fb56ad15\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.class]))

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ahmedkarray.switchsides.colorsdash"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true

    ndk {
        moduleName "player_shared"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }


}
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
}
}
android{


configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your dependencies this way

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){
       exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
}
```

Change also compileSdkVersion

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
```

And remove `support-v4-19.0.1.jar` from your libs folder